# How can I retrieve tags (key-value) information from a session id of AWS Glue Interactive session

Tags: aws-glue

Let's say I have a sesionid = abc and I have other information about the session like worker type, DPU seconds etc. If navigated to the next page by clicking on one of the session ids in AWS glue interactive session one can see the information like sessionid, configurations, default arguments, and below we can see Tags. I have been searching around boto3 documents to pythonically access the tags information but no luck.

Tried getting the session id information using the get_session() method